# Integer overflow checking

Tags: solidity, overflow

In the code of `Coin` contract at:

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#subcurrency-example

there is the following function which requires the amount to be smaller than `10^60`.

```
function mint(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == minter);
        require(amount < 1e60);
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }
```

I thought that the maximum number an `uint` can hold is `2^256 ~= 10^77`. According to doc:

> The second call to require ensures that there will not be too many
>   coins, which could cause overflow errors later.

What kind of overflow can be caused when the amount is bigger than `10^60 ~= 2^200` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a totally arbitrary number for the sake of the example, probably because someone will need to call the `mint` function `1.157920892373162e+17` times to actually have an overflow (if they mint an amount just under `1e60`).

Plus, it doesn't take in account potential overflow if you transfer tokens to someone else, but again this snippet of code in the solidity docs is just for example.

You should use the SafeMath library whenever you do sensitive arithmetical operations.

Answer (score 2):

That's a nasty way to do it and I don't think it's reliable.

Use the SafeMath method.

If `a + b = c`, then `c` must be more than `a` or an overflow has occured.

From SafeMath:

```
function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
  uint256 c = a + b;
  require(c >= a);
  return c;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am aware of SafeMath from OpenZeppelin. I was curious to learn if there is any meaning behind the specific choice of number or it's totally arbitrary.